# What's the best way to change DOM elements from service layers in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

The scenario is that I want to change the mouse cursor to waiting while we're waiting for the database to return it's data and for objects to render.

The structure of the project is:

`controller -> has multiple factory objects -> each use a service to interact with the server`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
//Represents a service that makes call to the server. 
//Returns angular promises
app.service('MyService', function($q, $timeout){

    this.evenOrOdd = function(i){

        console.log("even or odd for: " + i);
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function(){    
                console.log("starting time out");
                if (parseInt(i)) {

                    if (i%2 === 1) deffered.resolve("Odd:" + i);
                    else deffered.resolve("Even" + i);                  
                }
                else deffered.reject("That's not an int!");
            }, 3000);

        return deffered.promise;

    };


});


//Represents some business object 
//We may want several of these
app.factory('MyFactory', function(MyService){

    return function() {

            //Some object specific variable
            this.rand = Math.random();

            console.log("creating new factory object with rand = " + this.rand);

            this.oddCheck = function(i){            
                var promise = MyService.evenOrOdd(i);



                promise.then(function(value){               
                    console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);

                    }
                .bind(this));   

                promise.catch(function(value){
                    console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
                }.bind(this));

            };


    };

});


//Our controller, makes calls to update multiple objects at the same time
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyFactory) {

    $scope.factoryObject = new MyFactory();
    $scope.factoryObject2 = new MyFactory();

    $scope.showa = "displayed";
    $scope.showb = "hidden";

    $scope.myClick = function(){    

            $scope.factoryObject.oddCheck();
            $scope.factoryObject2.oddCheck();


    };


    }
);
```

Now while we're waiting for that service call to complete, we want to switch the mouse cursor to wait.

I could do it something like this:

```
app.factory('MyFactory', function(MyService, $document){

    return function() {

            //Some object specific variable
            this.rand = Math.random();

            console.log("creating new factory object with rand = " + this.rand);

            this.oddCheck = function(i){

                $document.find('body').attr('style', 'cursor:wait');  //<--
                var promise = MyService.evenOrOdd(i);



                promise.then(function(value){   
                    $document.find('body').attr('style', 'cursor:default');       //<--
                    console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);

                    }
                .bind(this));   

                promise.catch(function(value){
                    $document.find('body').attr('style', 'cursor:default');       //<--
                    console.log(this.rand + "|" + value);
                }.bind(this));

            };


    };

});
```

The problem of course with this, is that if one service call returns before the other it'll switch the mouse cursor back prematurely.

What's the accepted design pattern to handle this kind of functionality?

I have some ideas:

- Register callbacks with a DOM Handling service that keeps track of whether any processes are still running and switches DOM elements accordingly.
- Pass promises back to the controller and allow the controller to keep track of what the mouse state should be.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @peso_junior to the extent that a `service` should not be interacting with the DOM, however I do not see a problem with including this logic in a `controller` - after all, the `controller` is the glue that binds the model to the view, so it would only seem natural that the `controller` can inform the view that the model isn't ready (i.e. the promise hasn't yet resolved).

However, it doesn't look as though your factories are returning promises, which would provide any callers of the factory a guarantee that calls to `MyService` and any subsequent processing in the factory constructor have completed. Moreover, if both factories returned a promise, we could chain them together and execute code when they've both completed (i.e. set the cursor back to normal):

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyFactory) {

    var firstPromise = new MyFactory();
    var secondPromise = new MyFactory();

    var promiseArray = [firstPromise, secondPromise];

    // Write code to update the cursor here

    $.when.apply(this, promiseArray)
        .done(function(firstFactory, secondFactory) {
            // All promises have resolved, now we set the cursor back
            $scope.firstFactory = firstFactory;
            $scope.secondFactory = secondFactory;
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
           console.log('Error initializing factories');
        });

})
```

### UPDATE

`$.when` demonstration: http://plnkr.co/edit/SqPf212nE5GrSPcZdo5K

`$.when` is a [JQuery concept](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), and in one of its forms, it can accept either a single promise, or an array or promises - at this point, it aggregates the response statuses of each promise that was passed into one general status: if **all** promises resolve, the success callback (`done`) is fired, if **any** of the promises fail, the `error` call back is invoked. In our case, when the `success` callback is fired, the incoming parameters are the objects returned from each promise, available in the order they were passed. As such, we get our `firstFactory` and `secondFactory` here. `$.when` is super, super helpful when chaining any promises that may be unrelated, but whatever the reason you need to perform an action when they all complete.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Could you give a quick explanation of that `$.when.apply` line? - Does resolve all promises at once?

Comment: Just updated the answer with a section on `$.when`. It's a cool enough feature that it deserves some attention :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, you mustn't access the DOM from the service layer. It is also not a good idea to do it from the controller. If you can transfer the logic to some directive it would be the best way to do it.
Additionally, you should know that all services in angular, including the factories are singletons. So, it is not a good idea to use in other ways. In your case you can have a method inside the factory that executes your logic there (the random and the rest of the logic).